# Reading JSON file line by line in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

```
{
  "Recipes": [
    {
      "Tag": "Salad",
      "Ingredients": [
        "Tomato",
        "Olive oil",
        "Thyme",
        "Lemon",
        "Black Pepper",
        "Salt"
      ]
    }
}
```

I have this json file and I want to read Contents of Salad line by line in Unity's Script. Like Ingredients first line is tomato. Second line is Olive oil. Please help me.

Comment: What difference does it make if you literally "read line by line" (which seems not to be what you likely actually want) vs. if you just parse the JSON into an object format and then process it "element by element" (iterate the elements of `Ingredients`, which seems the typical thing to do)?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 1):

you have to download and install a special version of Newtonsoft.Json for Unity

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var recipes = JObject.Parse(json)["Recipes"].Dump();
    
    string[] saladIngridients = recipes
                   .Where(r => (string)r["Tag"] == "Salad")
                   .FirstOrDefault()["Ingredients"]
                   .Select(r => (string)r)
                   .ToArray();
                   
    foreach (string ingridient in saladIngridients)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ingridient);
    }
```

output

```
Tomato
Olive oil
Thyme
Lemon
Black Pepper
Salt
```